# PowerShell Script to confirm RCF compliant DN in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

First post!
This is an issue ive come across recently when an LDAP aware application that shall remain nameless is reporting an error in a DN in one of the 19 Domains in the forest but the vendor cant give me any further detail around what the object with the error is other than "We are pretty tight on RFC compliance so it could be anything and we see error 34"

Helpful right.

My other LDAP aware apps are perfectly fine so this is more of a "prove you wrong" type of exercise.
I have a list of DNs exported from every object that has changed in the last 10 days from every domain.
9 days ago is when the thing broke so would capture everything that they are trying to say it would be.

What im hoping to find out is if there is a way for me to run a PS script to check for RFC complaince in the DN string?
I have no ides whats involved with RFC, cant even find a clear explanation of what is and is not accepted.

Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: [This is likely the RFC in question](https://docs.ldap.com/specs/rfc4514.txt) - but, how do you pass the DNs to the application?

Comment: Just a bog standard LDAP lookup. It has been working fine for a long time, couple of years but there was a service outage so I had to recreate the 2 Azure connectors and this LDAP connector, but its now giving the error and not getting much help from the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but it's something that's burned me before: Do you have any accounts with forward slashes in their name? Even [Microsoft's own code has problems with that](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29090).

The DN would look something like:

```
CN=test/user,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

That's perfectly valid (at least AD allows it). But if you try to bind to that directly via LDAP, and you just drop it into an LDAP path, you get this:

```
LDAP://CN=test/user,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

However, in an LDAP path, forward slashes are special characters, so it sees the path as just `LDAP://CN=test`, which of course won't work. The slash must be escaped (just replace `/` with `\/`):

```
LDAP://CN=test\/user,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

To find out if you have any accounts with slashes in their name, you can do a query like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(cn=*/*))
```

In PowerShell, you could do that like this:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(cn=*/*)"
```

This could also happen if you have any OU's with slashes in their name.

Comment: There is one that was created in the last 10 days! 
Ive removed it now and replaced with a hyphen so will need to wait for a few syncs now to see if that does sort it.
Fingers crossed! 
I'll let you know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: If that does turn out to be it, I'd consider that a bug in the software. The RFC (at least the one Mathias linked to) doesn't say anything about a forward slash not being allowed in a DN. So they should be able to handle it.

Comment: It hasn't helped unfortunately, there are 99 other objects with the forward slash and these havent changed in months and have been syncing successfully so I doubt its any of them.
Ive tried another account in the LDAP connector which hasnt helped and now im trying to push the vendor into giving me another tenant hosted in the same region so I can enter the credentials into the connector outside of my tenant as im still not convinced its an issue in the AD environment.
I think its something there side so this would be nice evidence (as long as it worked) 
Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Too bad. Yeah, sounds like you'll just have to fight them for information. I've been there...